# How can I construct custom WebApi routes like "package/{packageName}/{controller}" to route to Application Parts in a separate assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

Our app loads controllers in external assemblies we call packages. I want to create a route that routes to a package using URLs like `package/BillingPackage/Invoice` rather than `api/BillingPackage/Invoice`. Here is what I have done:

## Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseEndpointRouting()
        .UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "package", 
            template: "package/{package}/{controller}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute("api", "api/{controller}/{action=Get}/{id?}");            
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}

public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var source = new PackageAssemblySource(Configuration);
    var packageAssemblies = source.Load();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new WebApiModule(packageAssemblies));

    services
        .AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
        {
            // Add controllers and parts from package assemblies.
            foreach (var assembly in packageAssemblies)
            {
                manager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
            }
        });
        .AddControllersAsServices() // Now that AssemblyParts are loaded.
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);;

    builder.Populate(services);
    ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

    return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
}
```

Then I define a controller like this:

```
[Route("package/BillingPackage/[controller]", Name = "Invoice")]
public class InvoiceController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult<Invoice> Get()
    {
        return new SampleInvoice();
    }
}
```

Even with all that, `package/BillingPackage/Invoice` yields a 404 whereas `api/BillingPackage/Invoice` does not. How do I get my WebApi to serve endpoints from `package` rather than `api`?

Comment: route conflict with `template: "package/{package}/{controller}/{id?}"`. If using attribute routing on the controller then remove that convention-based route

Comment: Interesting, but then how do I specify the package name "BillingPackage" if not with the route on the controller?

Comment: You've already hard-coded the package name in the attribute route template `package/BillingPackage/[controller]`

Comment: Yes, I see your point, but how can Controllers in a package specify the package name if not by attributes? How can those controllers get associated with that package name? Also, the RouteData always only contain `{"action":"Get","controller":"Customer"}` rather than having a value for `package`. What do I need to write to pluck that out of the URL?

Comment: you would need to include a template parameter `[Route("package/{package}/[controller]", Name = "Invoice")]` along with a method/action argument `public ActionResult<Invoice> Get(string package)` which will be populate from the matched value from the URL.

Comment: Thank you much, but why not create a full answer if you have time? I still don't see where the name of the package gets specified in your suggested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably experiencing route conflict with template:     `"package/{package}/{controller}/{id?}"`.

If using attribute routing on the controller then remove that convention-based route

To get the desired behavior, you would need to include a template parameter `[Route("package/{package}/[controller]", Name = "Invoice")]` along with a method/action argument `public ActionResult<Invoice> Get(string package)` which will be populated from the matched value from the URL.

For example

```
[Route("package/{package}/[controller]", Name = "Invoice")]
public class InvoiceController : ControllerBase {

    //GET package/BillingPackage/Invoice
    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult<Invoice> Get(string package) {
        return new SampleInvoice();
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)